# display real time graph of serial port data

Tags: c#, serial-port, zedgraph

I want to display graph of data coming from serial port.This data is continues having \r in between. For drawing graph I am using ZedGraph.dll. My code is as follows

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using ZedGraph;
using System.IO.Ports;
namespace FilterRealTimeCSharp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<double> measures;
        /// The ZedGraph curve
        LineItem myCurve;
        BackgroundWorker worker;
      //  ZedGraphControl zedGraphControl1;
        GraphPane myPane;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //create an empty list
            measures = new List<double>();

            myPane = zedGraphControl2.GraphPane;
            //init your zegGraphControl here
            //create an empty curve: it will be filled later
            myCurve = myPane.AddCurve("Porsche", null, Color.Red, SymbolType.Diamond);
            //create the worker
            worker = new BackgroundWorker();
            // set this to true so that you can cancel the worker
            worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
            worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            //the worker has completed
            //do whatever you want here

        }
        private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            //put all your serial port code here
            SerialPort sprt = new SerialPort("COM1");
            sprt.BaudRate = 9600;
            sprt.Parity = Parity.None;
            sprt.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            sprt.DataBits = 8;
            sprt.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            try
            {
                sprt.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Check port");
                return;
            }
            //worker.CancellationPending will change to true when CancelAsync is called
            //(so when the user clicks button2).
            //while the worker should still continue, read incoming data
            while (!worker.CancellationPending)
            {
                //wait for data to come...
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                string indata = sprt.ReadExisting();
                //extract the values from the read data
                //be careful here: make sure the read data is complete...
                string[] splt = indata.Split('\r');
               // string chop = splt[2];
               //// string final = chop.Remove(5);
               // float d = Convert.ToSingle(chop);
                //update the measures
                //measures is shared by several threads: you must lock it to access it safely

                lock (measures)
                {
                    for (int i = 1; i < splt.Length-2; i++)
                    {
                        string chop = splt[i];
                        // string final = chop.Remove(5);
                        float d = Convert.ToSingle(chop);
                        measures.Add(d);
                    }
                }
                //update the graph
                BeginInvoke((Action)(() => UpdateGraph()));
            }
            //user wants to stop the worker
            sprt.Close();
        }
        /// This function is called when the graph should be updated
        private void UpdateGraph()
        {
            //messures is shared by several threads: you must lock it to access it safely
            lock (measures)
            {
                //add each measure into the curve
                for (int i = 0; i < measures.Count; i++)
                {
                    //fill each with what ever you want
                    double x = myCurve.Points.Count;
                    double y = measures[i];
                    //add a new point to the curve
                    myCurve.AddPoint(x, y);
                }
                //all measures have been added
                //we can empty the list
                measures.Clear();
            }
            //the curve has been updated so refresh the graph
            zedGraphControl2.AxisChange();
            zedGraphControl2.Invalidate();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            worker.CancelAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

But It is not displaying continuous graph. I don't know where is the problem in my code.
Please help me to solve this problem.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try [RollingPointPairList](http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/documentation/html/T_ZedGraph_RollingPointPairList.htm) instead of list...?

there's an example for [Real Time Plot](http://goorman.free.fr/ZedGraph/zedgraph.org/wiki/index3061.html?title=Display_Dynamic_or_Real-Time_Data) using ZedGraph, Good Luck..:)

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you are clearing your measures list every time you plot the curve. Each time, ZedGraph is plotting a single point and erasing the rest of the curve. Maybe?